# Baffled by choice during install of Brother MFC-L2710DW on Debian

Tags: linux, debian, printer, brother-printer

I'm running Debian Stretch (well, actually, Devuan ASCII) on an AMD64 machine, and I want to install my new shiny printer/scanner machine, the MFC-2710DW, on it.

Actually, the printer stands alone and does not require installation itself - it's at IP X.Y.Z.W on my local network. But its clients do need an installation, and specifically - my Devuan box needs it (I think!).

So I went [here](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadhowto.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfcl2710dw_us_eu_as&os=128&dlid=dlf006893_000&flang=4&type3=625), I downloaded the installer, `gzip -d`'ed it and ran the resulting binary - as instructed on the linked-to page. The trouble was when I'd reached the end of the instructions: I've chosen to specify the device URI as instructed, and now I get:

```
Setting up mfcl2710dwpdrv:i386 (4.0.0-1) ...
lpadmin -p MFCL2710DW -E -v dnssd://Brother%20MFC-L2710DW%20series._ipp._tcp.local/?uuid=e3248000-80ce-11db-8000-3c2af473b484 -P /usr/share/ppd/brother/brother-MFCL2710DW-cups-en.ppd
#
Will you specify the Device URI? [Y/n] ->Y

0: socket
1: hp
2: http
3: https
4: beh
5: serial:/dev/ttyS0?baud=115200
6: ipp
7: ipp14
8: ipps
9: lpd
10: smb
11: hpfax
12: dnssd://Brother%20MFC-L2710DW%20series._ipp._tcp.local/?uuid=e3248000-80ce-11db-8000-3c2af473b484
13: lpd://printer/BINARY_P1
14 (I): Specify IP address.
15 (A): Auto. (dnssd://Brother%20MFC-L2710DW%20series._ipp._tcp.local/?uuid=e3248000-80ce-11db-8000-3c2af473b484)

select the number of destination Device URI. ->_
```

So,

- Which option should I select, for a network connection to X.Y.Z.W ?
- Do I have multiple options which should also work?
- What do I do afterwards?

Comment: I dont have this model printer, but socket and ipp are both very conmon and should work in any network printer, with socket being easier to set up. Otger then 1 4 and 5 they shoukd sll work. That said, option 15 is probably going to be the easiest to setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Choose the option "14 (I): Specify IP address"

This is not a "complete" solution, as in I'm still struggling with this printer, but the immediate choice seems to be: 14(I).

You will be prompted for the printer's IP address. You should have already configured that using the printer's LCD screen and buttons already; if not - do so. You now known which IP number to enter. For me it was X.Y.Z.W

Now try to print a test page; one should come out - a Debian-CUPS logo page.